# how do I get both the maximum and minumum out of list

Tags: python, compare, max

I have two tuples, for example

```
tup1 = (200,(b,5),(a,5))
tup2 = (500,(b,7),(a,3))
```

First, I want to find the tuple with the highest first element but if these are the same, I want to have the tuple with the lowest second element. But if the first two elements are equal to the first two elements of the other tuple, I have to have the tuple with the smallest third element. How can I do this correctly?

For this example the outcome has to be `tup_end = (500,(b,7),(a,3))` because the first element of tup2 is greater than that of tup.

if
`tup1 = (200,(b,5),(a,5))
 tup2 = (200,(b,7),(a,3))`
the outcome has to be `tup_end = (200,(b,5),(a,5))` because the first elements of tup1 and tup2 are equal but the second element of tup1 is smaller than that of tup2

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the expected output of your example?

Comment: Can't you do a loop and check all that?

Comment: Please add a more complete example and the expected output

Comment: `tup_end = min([tup1, tup2], key=function_which_create_object_to_compare)` ?

Comment: no because if the first elements are not the same i want to receive the tuple with the largest first element

Comment: you have to create function which create object to compare - ie it can add minus to first element - `(-first, rest)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min(..., key=function)` with function which creates item with negative first value and then you have to find the smallest `-first` and the smallest other values - instead of the biggest `first` value and the smallest other values - so you can use `min()` for all values in tuple

```
def create(item):
    first = item[0]
    rest = item[1:]
    return (-first, *rest)

a = 0
b = 0

tup1 = (200, (b,5), (a,5))
tup2 = (500, (b,7), (a,3))

tup_end = min([tup1, tup2], key=create)
print(tup_end)

tup1 = (200,(b,5),(a,5))
tup2 = (200,(b,7),(a,3))

tup_end = min([tup1, tup2], key=create)
print(tup_end)
```

Result

```
(500, (0, 7), (0, 3))
(200, (0, 5), (0, 5))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the follwing code:

```
lst = [2, 6, 8, 4, 3] # example of numeric lst
```

Get max:

```
print(max(lst)) # printed 8
```

Get min:

```
print(min(lst)) # printed 2
```

Dont forget to use `int(lst)` to make sure it's consisted of numeric values.

You can use the functions above to help you easily complete the exericise

Also works on tuples